# Does FetchType.LAZY fetch anything in list or it's empty

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

Let's say i have a association as ,

```
class Department{

......

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Employee> employees; 

}
```

Now when i fetch `Department`, will it fetch anything in `employees list` or will it be completely empty.

Will identifiers for employee object be loaded in list like say i have employee object attributes as below:-

```
Employee{
id
name
doj
....

}

Lazy object like {
id -> 111
name -> null
doj -> null

}
```

Now when i initialize employee object or access it's properties using getters, then the object will be loaded from database using id as an identifier...??

Comment: You could try it and see.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the real collection class (e.g. `ArrayList`) a different `List` implementation is injected into your field (`PersistentList`). Depending on the calls on that collection and the lazy strategy it will do different things:

- In case `lazy="lazy"` the call to any of the collections methods would get the collection fully loaded
- If `lazy="extra"`, then calls to some functions would trigger SQL without loading the collection. E.g. `list.size()` would trigger `select count...`.  While getting the 1st element would select only that element. This may be suitable for large collections. Note, that this behaviour may also depend on the collection type - unordered collections will load all elements anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy fetch type, Hibernate won’t load the relationships for that particular object instance.

`FetchType.LAZY` = Doesn’t load the relationships unless explicitly “asked for” via getters
`FetchType.EAGER` = Loads ALL relationships

In your case It won't load Employee List from database unless you explicitly  fire query for it, Because you  have set fetch type ( fetch = FetchType.LAZY ). If fetch type was ( fetch = FetchType.EAGER ) then It would explicitly fire a select query for Employee list. In that object you would get all employee property eg name, doj.

**the object will be loaded from database using id as an identifier...??**

```
Department{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,,mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Employee> employees; 
}
```

In Emplooyee.... You need to mapped it by reference of department object.
eg:

```
Employee{

    // Reference of department.

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "departmentid", nullable = false)
    private Department department;  
}
```

This way it will become bidirectional. now Hibernate will fire query by reference (id in native sql) .

If you want to be loaded lazily the set Fetch mode FetchType.LAZY in both mapping....

Comment: *FetchType.LAZY = Doesn’t load the relationships unless explicitly “asked for” via **getters*** : I believe it is wrong. Whenever you access the list (through most of its methods) it will trigger lazy loading.  It has nothing to do with "getters"

Comment: And, you do not need to map it as eager for a bi-directional relationship

Comment: yes i agree i just gave an example if you want eager loading then you need to write eg:  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,,mappedBy = "department") here. otherwise it will load nothing . Your set will be empty.

Comment: Sorry I cannot agree because : 1. it is not related what OP asked 2. *"your set will be empty"* : this is wrong.  The set (or collection) will be lazily loaded doesn't mean it will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your case until you explicitly access `Department.employees` (through a getter or any other means) It will not load the `Employee` entities. There will be a Proxy for this. It will be initialized once at the first call to access this `employees` collection.

Comment: will it hold primary key or any identifier.

Answer (score 0):

**How Lazy Loading Works in Hibernate**

The simplest way that Hibernate can apply lazy load behavior upon your entities and associations is by providing a proxy implementation of them. Hibernate intercepts calls to the entity by substituting a proxy for it derived from the entity’s class. Where the requested information is missing, it will be loaded from the database before control is ceded to the parent entity’s implementation.

Please note that when the association is represented as a collection class, then a wrapper (essentially a proxy for the collection, rather than for the entities that it contains) is created and substituted for the original collection. When you access this collection proxy then what you get inside returned proxy collection are not proxy entities; rather they are actual entities. You need not to put much pressure on understanding this concept because on runtime it hardly matters.

Please refer this for more information:
http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/lazy-loading-in-hibernate/

Also enable `hibernate.sql.show=true` so that you can see what queries are being fired when you are trying to fetch the collections.